# How to change radio button color and size in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

> I am using bootstrap but i can change radio button size and in his
>   color

Here is ml example

```
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> 1
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2"> 2
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3"> 3
</label>
```

Comment: Can you make an example of what you've got already and what you've tried so far? I suggest http://jsfiddle.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style radio button or checkbox inside a bootstrap table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237205/how-to-style-radio-button-or-checkbox-inside-a-bootstrap-table)

Answer (score 1):

Radiobuttons are handled by the browser, there is not really CSS that make this.

Byt there are two options to style the round circle of radiobuttons:

- Pure CSS
- Pictures

This website explain those two techniques quite well: [stephenmorley.org](http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/)

To be honest, it's quite difficult to have right design by CSS if you are targetting lots of different browsers, and it is the reason why I recommand you to use picture if you have large audience.

You can check this JSFiddle I've made for you for testing purposes https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16879/

```
<div class="container">
    <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> 1
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2"> 2
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3"> 3
</label>

</div>
```

Comment: But i can change radio button round border color

Comment: You can't stylize all properties of native elements (select, input, textarea, etc), so you need to workaround with CSS or any javascript plugin.

Comment: But i can't use java script plugin only use css

Comment: You cannot just change the color of button, button are styled by browser. If you want to handle this, it will be more complicated but it is possible. have a look to those two methods http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: check it material design radio button he is change all style without javascript

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean @AshuDesigner both medhot There is in the website I gave you is without js

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/radioButton
In this link show example of apple,Banana,Mango i want to same radio button
@clement

Comment: it's from the angular material, do you use angular in your webapp? https://material.angularjs.org/latest/

Comment: @AshuDesigner please consider validate my answer. thanks

Comment: This answer is not for bootstrap radio buttons which are clearly styled.

Answer (score -1):

The color is changed by adding a bootstrap button class definition to the label that encapsulates the radio input element.

```
<div class="container">
    <label class="radio-inline btn btn-danger">
  <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> 1
</label>
<label class="radio-inline btn btn-success">
  <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2"> 2
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3"> 3
</label>

</div>
```